# Do any computer languages not use a stack?

Tags: data-structures, programming-languages

Do any computer languages not use a stack data structure to keep track of execution progress?

Or is the use of this data structure an emergent requirement stemming from something inherent to most computer languages or turing machines?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve the question to avoid closing.

Comment: what do you mean by writing "is this universal?" can you be more specific? maybe this question is more related to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a traditional "C-style" stack, certain language features are difficult or impossible to implement. For example, closures can't easily be implemented with a traditional stack because closures require a pointer to an old activation record to work correctly and that memory is automatically reclaimed in a C-style stack. As another example, generators and coroutines need their own memory to store local variables and relative offset information and therefore can't easily be implemented if you use a standard stack implementation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: JavaScript implements closures, but retains a stack data-structure to record the activation records. Is it simply that the LIFO behavior of stacks is exactly what is needed by computer languages and LIFO defines a stack?

Comment: @BenAston A stack works because the way in which normal function call and return works is such that only the current function is active, calling a function suspends that function and activates a new one, and returning from a function completely ends the memory for the function call and exposes the most-recently-called function. That's exactly the behavior you get from a stack. The examples I've given above show that these constraints don't necessarily have to hold, so you can't always use a stack in the C-style model.